# Dynamically access column value in record

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, procedures

Is it possible to dynamically access a column value from a record by its name?

I'm writing a trigger function that executes a dynamic SQL command and I would like to dynamically extract a column value from a `NEW` record by column name.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$$
DECLARE
   command text := 'UPDATE $1 SET $2 = $3';
   myColumn := 'votes'
BEGIN
   EXECUTE command using 'anotherTable', myColumn, NEW.myColumn;
END
$$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's **possible**, but the `USING` clause of `EXECUTE` can only pass ***values***, while ***identifiers*** like table and column names must be concatenated in the command string. (Be wary of SQL injection!)   Using [**`format()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) it could work like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION ... AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _command text := 'UPDATE %I SET %I = $1 WHERE ....';  -- add WHERE condition
   _col text := 'votes';
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(_command, 'anotherTable', _col)
   USING  NEW.myColumn;
END
$func$;
```

Fixed a couple of minor problems in passing.

It must be mentioned that `NEW` is only available in trigger functions.

Be aware that `'anotherTable'` is ***case sensitive*** here (being concatenated safely with double-quotes from a *string*), while `NEW.myColumn` is not (processed as unquoted identifier). Always use legal, lower case, unquoted identifiers in Postgres to make your life easier.

Related answers with more explanation and links:

- [PL/pgSQL: General Way to Update N Columns in Trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148585/pl-pgsql-general-way-to-update-n-columns-in-trigger)
- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

---

> *To dynamically extract a column value from a `NEW` record by column name.*

... you can use the [hstore **`#=`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE):

- [How to set value of composite variable field using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711432/how-to-set-value-of-composite-variable-field-using-dynamic-sql/7782641#7782641)

Or you can make it work with standard features of dynamic SQL as well:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ... AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _col text := 'votes';
   _new_col text := 'column_name_in_new';  -- case-sensitive column name here
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
       'UPDATE %I SET %I = $1.%I WHERE ... '  -- add WHERE condition
     , 'anotherTable', _col, _new_col)
   USING  NEW;  -- pass whole row
END
$func$;
```

Related:

- [Creating a trigger for child table insertion returns confusing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321091/creating-a-trigger-for-child-table-insertion-returns-confusing-error/27340540#27340540)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, however that's still not quite what I was trying to do.

In your example you explicitly accessed `NEW.myColumn;` I would like to dynamically access a column based on a pre-existing value, something like `NEW[_column]`.

Someone suggested elsewhere to use **hstore**. This works: `hstore(NEW)->_column` to access the _votes_ column in NEW dynamically. However I'm not familiar at all with hstore and I would prefer not to enable the extension if there's a simpler alternative.

Comment: @RedHusky: I added another solution for that.

Comment: thank you for this great answer, helped me to solve a problem.