# Merge multiple result tables and perform final query on result

Tags: postgresql, parameter-passing, aggregate-functions, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a function returning table, which accumulates output of multiple calls to another function returning table. I would like to perform final query on built table before returning result. Currently I implemented this as ***two functions***, one accumulating and one performing final query, which is ugly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_accu(LOCATION_ID INTEGER, SCHEMA_CUSTOMER TEXT)
  RETURNS TABLE("networkid" integer, "count" bigint) AS $$
DECLARE
GATEWAY_ID integer;
BEGIN
    FOR GATEWAY_ID IN
        execute format(
            'SELECT id FROM %1$I.gateway WHERE location_id=%2$L'
           , SCHEMA_CUSTOMER, LOCATION_ID)
    LOOP
        RETURN QUERY execute format(
            'SELECT * FROM get_available_networks_gw(%1$L, %2$L)'
           , GATEWAY_ID, SCHEMA_CUSTOMER);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_query(LOCATION_ID INTEGER, SCHEMA_CUSTOMER TEXT)
  RETURNS TABLE("networkid" integer, "count" bigint) AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY execute format('
       SELECT networkid, max(count) FROM func_accu(%2$L, %1$L) GROUP BY networkid;'
     , SCHEMA_CUSTOMER, LOCATION_ID);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can this be done in ***single function***, elegantly?

Comment: Remember to always provide your version of Postgres and the necessary context - at least the exact result type of `get_available_networks_gw(..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions simplified and merged, also supplying *value* parameters in the [`USING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.func_accu(_location_id integer, schema_customer text)
  RETURNS TABLE(networkid integer, count bigint) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('
      SELECT f.networkid, max(f.ct)
      FROM   %I.gateway g
           , get_available_networks_gw(g.id, $1) f(networkid, ct)
      WHERE  g.location_id = $2
      GROUP  BY 1'
    , _schema_customer)
   USING  _schema_customer, _location_id;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM func_accu(123, 'my_schema');
```

Related:

- [Dynamically access column value in record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490615/dynamically-access-column-value-in-record/32490839#32490839)

I am using alias names for the columns returned by the function (`f(networkid, ct)`) to be sure because you did not disclose the return type of `get_available_networks_gw()`. You can use the column names of the return type directly.

The comma (`,`) in the `FROM` clause is short syntax for `CROSS JOIN LATERAL ...`. Requires Postgres **9.3 or later**.

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Or you could run this query instead of the function:

```
SELECT f.networkid, max(f.ct)
FROM   myschema.gateway g, get_available_networks_gw(g.id, 'my_schema') f(networkid, ct)
WHERE  g.location_id = $2
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is perfect and well explained!