# insert into select from in pg/gp function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I'm Newbie in postgres. I wrote a function, which insert into table a data by portions(because there is too much data in the source table to do it all at once) from another table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_load(p_src_schema character varying, p_src_tab character varying,p_tgt_schema character varying, p_tgt_tab character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    table_rec record;
BEGIN
    FOR table_rec IN
        SELECT otchdor, descr
        FROM otchdor
        ORDER BY otchdor
    loop
        insert into p_tgt_schema||'.'||p_tgt_tab
        select from p_src_schema||'.'||p_src_tab
        where  otchdor = table_rec.otchdor;
    end loop;
    return;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql 
;
```

got SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "||"

How correctly concat schema and table names at query?
Where did I go wrong?

use:
PostgreSQL 9.4.24 (Greenplum Database 6.14.0 build commit:Open Source) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 6.4.0, 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

For that you need dynamic sql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_load(p_src_schema character varying, p_src_tab character varying,p_tgt_schema character varying, p_tgt_tab character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    table_rec record;
BEGIN
    FOR table_rec IN
        SELECT otchdor, descr
        FROM otchdor
        ORDER BY otchdor
    loop
        EXECUTE  'insert into ' || quote_nullable(p_tgt_schema) || '.' || quote_nullable(p_tgt_tab) ||
        ' select * from ' || quote_nullable(p_src_schema) || '.' || quote_nullable(p_src_tab)  ||
        ' where  otchdor = ' || quote_nullable(table_rec.otchdor);
    end loop;
    return;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql 
;
```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8YGAPLSc)

Comment: Your code is SQL injection vulnerable. When you use dynamic SQL, then all text type parameters should be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Greenplum copied Postgres 9.4 functionality for PL/pgSQL functions. I don't actually use Greenplum.

Use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`. Best with `format()` to concatenate the query string comfortably and safely:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_load(p_src_schema text, p_src_tab text, p_tgt_schema text, p_tgt_tab text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT AS
$func$
DECLARE
   rec record;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN
      SELECT otchdor
      FROM   otchdor
      ORDER  BY otchdor
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format (
        'INSERT INTO %I.%I
         SELECT * FROM %I.%I
         WHERE  otchdor = $1'
       , p_tgt_schema, p_tgt_tab, p_src_schema, p_src_tab)
      USING rec.otchdor;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

The format specifier `%I` is for identifiers and correlates to `quote_ident()`. Either double-quotes identifiers safely as needed, to defend against SQL injection and syntax errors. `quote_nullable()` (like has been suggested) would be nonsense for identifiers. Also, best pass the *value* as (typed) value with the `USING` clause See:

- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [Dynamically access column value in record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490615/dynamically-access-column-value-in-record/32490839#32490839)

Also, the DDL command would fail if any identifier was `null`, so I made the function `STRICT`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#id-1.9.3.67.6)

> If this parameter is specified, the function is not executed when there are null arguments; instead a null result is assumed automatically.

But I don't think this function makes much sense to begin with. Chopping up that big `INSERT` would make sense with separate transactions (like you could employ in a `PROCEDURE` in modern Postgres, but not in Greenplum). A function always runs inside a single transaction anyway.