# EXECUTE of SELECT ... INTO is not implemented

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, partitioning

I am trying to run this function in PostrgeSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_partition_and_insert()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
partition VARCHAR(25);
_date text;
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'SELECT REPLACE(' || quote_literal(NEW.date) || ',''-'',''_'') into _date';
partition := TG_RELNAME || '_' || _date || ‘p’;
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname=partition) THEN
RAISE NOTICE 'A partition has been created %',partition;
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || partition || ' (check (date = ''' || NEW.date || ''')) INHERITS (' || TG_RELNAME || ');';
END IF;
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || partition || ' SELECT(' || TG_RELNAME || ' ' || quote_literal(NEW) || ').*;';
RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But on running this I get this as error:

> ```
> ERROR:  EXECUTE of SELECT ... INTO is not implemented
> HINT:  You might want to use EXECUTE ... INTO or EXECUTE CREATE TABLE ... AS instead.
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function create_partition_and_insert() line 6 at EXECUTE statement
> ```

I have no clue why this is happening and none of the solutions provided online are helping me here.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Instead of

```
execute 'select 1 into i'    -- error
```

you should use

```
execute 'select 1' into i
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message is the least of the problems in this function. Consider a complete rewrite.

Assuming the column `date` is actually data type `date`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_partition_and_insert()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _partition text := quote_ident(TG_RELNAME
                               || to_char(NEW.date,'_YYYY_MM_DD"p"'));
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname = _partition) THEN
      EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %s (CHECK (date = %L)) INHERITS (%I);'
                   , _partition, NEW.date, TG_RELNAME);

      RAISE NOTICE 'A new partition has been created: %', _partition;
   END IF;

   EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %s SELECT ($1).*', _partition)
   USING NEW;

   RETURN NULL;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Major points

- You don't need dynamic SQL in your first statement at all (the source or your syntax error). Actually, you don't need the whole statement nor the variable. I radically simplified the name concatenation. [Details for `to_char()` in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)
- Ignoring the typographical quotes in `‘p’` - those are probably just c/p artefacts.
- Assignments are comparatively expensive in plpgsql. Adapt your programming style and reduce variables and assignments.
- Don't convert the whole row to its text representation, concatenate and then cast it back. That's needlessly expensive, convoluted and error-prone. Pass the *value* directly in a `USING` clause to `EXECUTE` like demonstrated.
- Don't raise the notice before it's done. `RAISE` is not rolled back in the case of an exception leading to potentially misleading log entries.
- If you have more than one schema in your database (which is common), your code is still unsafe. You need to schema-qualify table names or `SET` the `search_path` for the function.

Related answers with more details:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)
- [Creating a trigger for child table insertion returns confusing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321091/creating-a-trigger-for-child-table-insertion-returns-confusing-error/27340540#27340540)
- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)
- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL official documentation (as on 12 July 2022) clearly calls out that as below:

> `SELECT INTO` is not currently supported within `EXECUTE`; instead, execute a plain `SELECT` command and specify `INTO` as part of the `EXECUTE` itself.

Something like below worked for me.

```
v_query_string = 'SELECT count(*) FROM foo';
EXECUTE v_query_string into v_count;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).